# The best way to make almost similar tabs in the tab bar controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar as a root view controller each tab is a navigation controller with detail view controller as a root.

I need several tabs that have almost same logic but separate values for properties. I thought the best way is to use the same vc and set properties in the init method. Something like:

```
[[MyViewController alloc] initWithStyle:MyCustomStyle]
```

But I don't see where to call this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're creating your UI using a nib or a storyboard. If so, yes, doing custom initialisation of `UIViewController`s or subclasses isn't supported -- the designated initialiser is called for you.

Possible workarounds:

- create your `UITabBarController` programmatically: this way you can instantiate your VCs any way you like
- have `MyViewController` find out which instance it actually is upon instantiation and set itself up accordingly -- by, for example, looking at its containing view controller and poking around with that (e.g. finding out what tab index it is)

The first option is the far nicer one, since it's cleaner and doesn't involve `MyViewController` having to know about its potential placement in a `UITabBarController` or similar (which is very hacky).

Comment: Yes, I'm creating from a storyboard. Strange that such a trivial thing isn't supported. Many thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are relying on NIBs to instantiate and initialize your nav controllers, you can use several tricks to tell each one what it is.

Simpliest one is to tse Tag in NIB, and handle different values in **initWithNibName:bundle:**, **initWithCoder:**, or  **viewDidLoad**

Comment: Better way is to create base class and derive each root nav controller from base, reference each class in NIB.  Easier to support if differences between controllers start to grow.